# Unable to read any config from Karate-config.js

Tags: javascript, automation, karate

I have created the karate-config.js under src/test/java
Tried directly using baseUrl or providing the systems property didn't worked

```
function fn() {

  var config = {
      env: env,
      baseUrl: 'http://testDev1/service',
      headers: headers,
   };

   var env = karate.env ? karate.env : "dev";
      var baseUrl = 'https://' + env + '.service/endpt';
      var version = '0.1.0';
    karate.log("The value of env is: ",  env);
  var headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'SRV.DEVICEID': 'test1.com',
    'CONSUMER.ID': '2caf5274'
  };
 var qaheaders = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'SRV.DEVICEID': 'test22.com',
    'CONSUMER.ID': '1111'
  };

  switch (env) {
    case "stg1":
      config.baseUrl = "https://testStg1/service";
      env = "stg";
      break;
    case "qa":
      config.baseUrl = "https://testqa1/service";
      env = "qa";
      headers = qaheaders;
      break;
   case "stg2":
      config.baseUrl = "https://teststg2/service";
      env = "qa";
      headers = headers;
      break;

  }

  return config;
}
```

in feature file I am doing something like this

```
@test122
Feature: Basic end-to-end testing

  Background:
    * url baseUrl

  Scenario:
    Given print baseUrl
    Given print env
```

Test runner file

```
class BasicApiTestingRunner {

    @Karate.Test
    Karate testBasicApi() {
        System.setProperty("-Dkarate.config.dir", "/Users/user/Development/project/src/test/java/karate-config.js");
        return Karate.run()
                .tags("@test122")
                .relativeTo(getClass());
    }
}
```

Error :

```
* url baseUrl
js failed:
>>>>
01: baseUrl
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "baseUrl" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

PS. similar code is working under 0.9.6 version current upgraded version 1.4.0

as per official document https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#karate-configjs, I tried same file structure as well still same behavior.

Comment: the only way others can help you is if you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2468

Comment: your command was incorrect, have responded and closed